# Drag and drop captcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm not a javascript developper but in this case I have to use javascript.

I'm making a web site and I want an original captcha, I want to drang and drop and image, and then automactly redirect to another page.

This wath I made, and its working but I dont know how to make the redirection when the image has been drag to right div.

```
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {

    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data= ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


</script>
```

And the HTML is

```
<table class="CTinCT">
<tr>
    <td>

        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

            <img src="imagen.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="200px" height="100px" />

        </div>

        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>



    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**How can I do the redirect?**

If you have a complete different way to do it please share.

Thanks, 
Boris.

Comment: `window.location = 'http://google.com'` <- javascript redirect

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put that?

Comment: Probably in the `drop` function

Comment: let me see, thak you

Comment: It was easy thank you its working

Answer (score 1):

In the function drop:

```
window.location = 'http://google.com' ;
```

Thank you adeneo: https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo